# Can Mathematica communicate with Keysight instruments?

Tags: automation

I am building an electronics lab with Keysight digital multimeters, power supplies, oscilloscopes, electrometers, etc. Is it possible for Mathematica to send commands from my MacBook Pro to these instruments and also read in data from these instruments?

Comment: To answer strictly to the question in the title : Yes, Mathematica can communicate with Keysight instruments. I do this regularly, but it is under Windows.

Comment: @andre314 How do you do this under Windows?

Comment: I don't know what Keysight is, but generally connected instruments on Unix-like OS's expose their functionality via psuedo-files in /dev. Mathematica can read and write such things using functions like `ReadLine` and `WriteLine`.

Comment: @John Doty Where is /dev on a mac?

Comment: It's at /dev, of course ツ. Try `FileNames["/dev/*"]` in *Mathematica* to see what's there.

Comment: In general, I send SCPI intructions to a GPIB link via VISA32.DLL. Mathematica send directly the SCPI strings to VISA32.DLL.